# c# xUnit Moq It.IsAny<object> not mocking as expected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, xunit

Following is the piece of code(simple HTTP post call), I am trying to mock in Azure Function:

```
await httpClient.PostAsync("https://url.com", await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_DIRECTORY"), "file.json"));
```

Note that the httpClient.PostAsync() function takes two arguments: URL as string and body as object.

Now, in my test, I am mocking this POST call like this:

```
httpClientMock.Setup(s => s.PostAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>())).ReturnsAsync(mockedHttpResponse);
```

I was expecting that `await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_DIRECTORY"), "file.json")` would not be called as I set it to work with any object. However, my test case fails with this exception:

> Found System.ArgumentNullException with message "Value cannot be null.
>   (Parameter 'path1')"
>            at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)

When I provide the correct path(even a dummy path doesn't work) by setting up the Environment variable in Test, it works. But that doesn't seem the correct way, as the unit tests are intended to run in various machines and the base path will be different for each one of them.

Comment: Moq is only going to deal with the parameter passed in, and you're allowing it to accept any object. The method creating that object still needs to be evaluated before it's sent to your Moq'd function, and this is where it's failing on an invalid parameter sent to `Path.Combine`.

Comment: Thanks @JonathonChase! I understand now. However, how to handle these situations, of course without rewriting the actual code?

Comment: Please show your complete test; otherwise, we're just guessing at how you have things set up. Also, `as the unit tests are intended to run in various machines`: that means they are integration tests, not unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

`File.ReadAllTextAsync()` returns a string, so your MOQ setup should have `It.IsAny<string>()` as the second param instead of `It.IsAny<object>()`.

Comment: Tried that before. Didn't work. Please refer Jonathan's comment on original question for justification. Seems about right.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you haven't actually intercepted the call to `File.ReadAllTextAsync(...);`

Remember that

```cs
await httpClient.PostAsync("https://url.com", 
    await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_DIRECTORY"), "file.json"));
```

is functionally the same as:

```cs
var fileContent = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_DIRECTORY"), "file.json");

await httpClient.PostAsync("https://url.com", fileContent);
```

This way it's more obvious that, even if you mock `httpClient.PostAsync`, the call to `File.ReadAllTextAsync` still happens.